# "Flickering images" with ViewHolder pattern when downloading images from server

Tags: java, android, imageview, android-viewholder

I want to create a list of Views, where the images shown in each View is downloaded from a server as you scroll the list (lazy loading). This is the code I have got so far:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Component> {

    private final List<Component> components;
    private final Activity activity;

    public CustomAdapter(Activity context, List<Component> components) {
        super(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, components);
        this.components = components;
        this.activity = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null, false);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);

            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        Component component = components.get(position);
        // Don't show any image before the correct one is downloaded
        viewHolder.imageView.setImageBitmap(null);

        if (component.getImage() == null) { // Image not downloaded already
            new DownloadImageTask(viewHolder.imageView).execute(component);
        } else {
            viewHolder.imageView.setImageBitmap(component.getImage());
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;
    }

    private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<Component, Void, Component> {

        private ImageView imageView;

        public DownloadImageTask(ImageView imageView) {
            this.imageView = imageView;
        }

        @Override
        protected Component doInBackground(Component... params) {
            String url = params[0].getImageURL();
            Component component = params[0];
            // Download the image using the URL address inside found in component
            Bitmap image = ImageDownloader.getImage(url);
            // Set the Bitmap image to the component so we don't have to download it again
            component.setImage(image);
            return component;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Component component) {
            // Update the ImageView with the downloaded image and play animation
            imageView.setImageBitmap(component.getImage());
            Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(activity, R.anim.fade_in);
            imageView.startAnimation(animation);
        }
    }
}
```

Basically, when getView() is run it gets data (in this case a Bitmap) from Component (which is used to cache data from the item), unless there is no data. In that case it executes the DownloadImageTask which will download the image and store it inside a Component. Once it's stored it puts the image in the ImageView.

My problem is that when using the ViewHolder pattern the ImageViews, instead of the "wrong way" (calling findViewById() each time), scrolling through the list will make the wrong ImageViews get the downloaded Bitmap. This gif shows how it looks:

[Preview](http://i.imgur.com/Bysjw2z.gif)

Obviously, I want the images to only appear where they should. Is there any good way to make this work as supposed to?

Comment: what is wrong with you? use Picasso to load your image. using async task for that is absolutely stupid.

Comment: This is because of the asynchronous nature of loading the images and the fact that `ListView` recyclers (read: reuses) views. Basically an image load is started for a certain row, then when you start scrolling a row which still has an ongoing image load goes off screen and gets reused to visualise a new item, for which yet another image load is kicked off. The 'old' image load now finishes and sets the image, and then the 'new' image load finishes too and sets a different image. Hence the 'flickering'. Long story short: do yourself a favour and use a dedicated library like Picasso or Glide.

Comment: Oh, haven't stumbled upon Picasso or Glide yet. Will definitely check them out, thanks!

@ViktorYakunin I guess lack of knowledge could be my problem. ;)

Comment: There are many [image loading libraries available for Android](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/46), most of which handle this sort of work for you. Whether you use Picasso, Glide, Universal Image Loader, or any of the others, you really want to use one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While others are right that there are many libraries that can handle this for you, it is possible to do it the way you tried initially if you really want to. You just need to make sure you cancel AsyncTasks when the item view is recycled. You can do this by adding the AsyncTask to your ViewHolder class, so you can see if there's something running and cancel it before starting a new one.

```
private class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageView;
    AsyncTask<?,?,?> task;
}
```

Then in your getView():

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ...

    // Don't show any image before the correct one is downloaded
    viewHolder.imageView.setImageBitmap(null);

    if (viewHolder.task != null) { // Existing task may be executing
        viewHolder.task.cancel(true);
        viewHolder.task = null;
    }

    if (component.getImage() == null) { // Image not downloaded already
        AsyncTask<?,?,?> task = new DownloadImageTask(viewHolder.imageView);
        viewHolder.task = task;
        task.execute(component);
    } else {
        viewHolder.imageView.setImageBitmap(component.getImage());
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I used Glide to solve the problem. Thanks everyone for informing me there already existed such wonderful things!

Doing (almost) the same thing was as easy as:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null, false);

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    String url = components.get(position).getImageURL();
    Glide.with(activity).load(url).crossFade().into(viewHolder.imageView);

    return convertView;
}
```